# Obfuscating passwords with single quotes in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to rexex

```
PASSWORD 'dsfad'
paSsword       'asdfa'
PAssWord   'asdrd'''
password  'asd''asdf'; password 'asdf'
```

to become

```
password '*****'
password '*****'
password '*****'
password '*****'
password '*****'; password '*****'
```

I have tried the following

```
re.compile("password\s*'[^']+['|''']", re.IGNORECASE).sub("password '*****'", "PASSWORD 'adfsdf'  password   'dadaskjh'    PaSsWoRd 'kkj''hjubkjn'''")
re.compile("password\s*'[^']+'", re.IGNORECASE).sub("password '*****'", "PASSWORD 'adfsdf'  password   'dadaskjh'    PaSsWoRd 'kkj''hjubkjn'''")
```

though it seems to be having trouble with the extra `'` and stopping the regex revealing half of the password.

EDIT:

These passwords are from postgres logs. The double `''` is escaping.

Comment: If the password is allowed to contain unescaped single quotes, how do we know that on the last line `'asd''asdf'; password 'asdf'` isn't one big password?

Comment: It looks like quotes are escaped by repeating them, is that right? So `''` within a password should be ignored.

Comment: These passwords are logged from postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in your input single quotes within passwords are escaped by repeating them. If so, within your regex you want to match a sequence of either two single quotes, or any individual character that is not a single quote.

```
password\s*'(''|[^'])+'
```

Answer (score 2):

This one does the trick:

```
password\s*'(''|[^'])*'
```

Read as:

```
password    the word "password"
\s*         zero or more whitespace characters
'           a single quote
(           zero or more of either...
    ''          a doubled quote
    |           or
    [^']        a character that is not a quote
)*
'           a single quote
```

Because the `*` operator is greedy, it won't just stop at the first quote it encounters.

Note that this also matches empty passwords.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
'(.*?)'
```

Comment: `re.compile("password\s*'(.*?)'", re.IGNORECASE).sub("password '*****'", "PASSWORD 'adfsdf'  password   'dadaskjh'    PaSsWoRd 'kkj''hjubkjn''asdf'''")`
`"password '*****'  password '*****'    password '*****''hjubkjn''asdf'''"`